# Converter parte de uma string em uma lista de listas

Tags: python, lista

Estou com um dúvida e não sei se pode ser feito no python
eu tenho uma lista de um elemento, esse elemento é uma string, dentro dessa string contém partes que eu gostaria de transformar numa lista.

```
lista1 = ['[\'Indicador\', \'Abílio Santana\', \'Média BA\', \'Média Brasil\'],["1",0.9,3.3,4.0],["2",0.9,2.5,3.7],["3",0.9,2.4,3.6],["4",0.0,0.2,0.5],["5",0.0,0.7,1.0],["6",0.0,2.0,3.0],["7",10.0,9.1,8.6],["8",0.9,3.0,3.1],\n']
```

Eu gostaria de saber se há como converter cada conteúdo que ta entre colchetes em um elemento de uma lista. Um output como a lista2 abaixo. Meu interesse posterior é em um dos valores (no segundo) de cada lista que irá se formar

```
lista2 = [[\'Indicador\', \'Abílio Santana\', \'Média BA\', \'Média Brasil\'], ["1",0.9,3.3,4.0], ["2",0.9,2.5,3.7], ["3",0.9,2.4,3.6], ["4",0.0,0.2,0.5], ["5",0.0,0.7,1.0], ["6",0.0,2.0,3.0], ["7",10.0,9.1,8.6], ["8",0.9,3.0,3.1]]
```

Eu tentei usar o `split(',[')`, mas ele sempre elimina o colchete e fiquei perdido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser obtida através da função [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

O módulo [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) é utilizado para processar árvores da gramática de sintaxe abstrata do Python.
Use a função `literal_eval()` para analisar uma string contendo um literal Python que pode ser:

- [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)
- [sequencias de bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview)
- [tipos numéricos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)
- [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)
- [listas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)
- [dicionários](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)
- [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
- [booleanos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)
- [None](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-null-object)
- [reticências](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object)

> Não use `literal_eval()` para avaliar strings de fonte não confiável
> pois mesmo não apresentando risco de injeção de código, por somente
> fazer a análise de literais, uma entrada muito longa, complexa ou
> maliciosamente preparada pode travar o interpretador Python devido às
> limitações de profundidade da pilha no compilador de AST do Python.

No seu caso apenas passe a string contida em `lista1` para `literal_eval()` e converta o retorno em [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

```python
from ast import literal_eval

lista1 = ['[\'Indicador\', \'Abílio Santana\', \'Média BA\', \'Média Brasil\'],["1",0.9,3.3,4.0],["2",0.9,2.5,3.7],["3",0.9,2.4,3.6],["4",0.0,0.2,0.5],["5",0.0,0.7,1.0],["6",0.0,2.0,3.0],["7",10.0,9.1,8.6],["8",0.9,3.0,3.1],\n']

print(list(literal_eval(lista1[0])))
#[ ['Indicador', 'Abílio Santana', 'Média BA', 'Média Brasil'], 
#  ['1', 0.9, 3.3, 4.0], ['2', 0.9, 2.5, 3.7], ['3', 0.9, 2.4, 3.6], 
#  ['4', 0.0, 0.2, 0.5], ['5', 0.0, 0.7, 1.0], ['6', 0.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
#  ['7', 10.0, 9.1, 8.6], ['8', 0.9, 3.0, 3.1] ]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/yB8IwU)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado, mais uma ferramenta aprendida.

Answer (score -1):

```
lista1 = [r'[\'Indicador\', \'Abílio Santana\', \'Média BA\', \'Média Brasil\'],["1",0.9,3.3,4.0],["2",0.9,2.5,3.7],["3",0.9,2.4,3.6],["4",0.0,0.2,0.5],["5",0.0,0.7,1.0],["6",0.0,2.0,3.0],["7",10.0,9.1,8.6],["8",0.9,3.0,3.1]']

res = lista1[0].split(',[')

count =0 
novaLista = []
for c in res:
     aux = res[count].strip(r'\[\\\]').split(',')
     novaLista.extend(aux)
     count = count +1
     if (count == res.index):
         break
print(count)

print(novaLista)
#["'Indicador\\'", " \\'Abílio Santana\\'", " \\'Média BA\\'", " \\'Média Brasil\\'", '"1"', '0.9', '3.3', '4.0', '"2"', '0.9', '2.5', '3.7', '"3"', '0.9', '2.4', '3.6', '"4"', '0.0', '0.2', '0.5', '"5"', '0.0', '0.7', '1.0', '"6"', '0.0', '2.0', '3.0', '"7"', '10.0', '9.1', '8.6']

print(novaLista[0])
#'Indicador\'

print(res)
#["[\\'Indicador\\', \\'Abílio Santana\\', \\'Média BA\\', \\'Média Brasil\\']", '"1",0.9,3.3,4.0]', '"2",0.9,2.5,3.7]', '"3",0.9,2.4,3.6]', '"4",0.0,0.2,0.5]', '"5",0.0,0.7,1.0]', '"6",0.0,2.0,3.0]', '"7",10.0,9.1,8.6]', '"8",0.9,3.0,3.1]']
print(res[0])
#[\'Indicador\', \'Abílio Santana\', \'Média BA\', \'Média Brasil\']
```

caso queira transformar em varias lista com base no colchetes so usar o valor de res